# How to autofill with a named cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use autofill on a named cell.

In a **really simplified version** of my code I set `Lastrow` to be the last row of a worksheet.

```
Lastrow = wsDest.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Row 
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set DragDownCell1 = wsDest.Cells(Lastrow, "B")
DragDownCell1 = 2.24334E+18
```

Then a For loop fills information into `Lastrow`. At the end of the loop I add 1 to `Lastrow` so adding information to the last row and doesn't overwrite itself.

```
For x = i + 1
    Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
Next x
```

Then I try to autofill 2.24334E+18 down to the last row but I get a method range error.

```
ws.Dest.Range("DragDownCell1").AutoFill Destination:=wsDest.Range(DragDownCell1, Cells(Lastrow, "B")), Type:=xFillDefault
```

I tested this out in another worksheet where I just test using a named cell

```
Cell1 = Range("H14")
Range("Cell1").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(14, 8), Cells(24, 8)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I get a method range of object global error.

Comment: `Range(DragDownCell1` is not the same as `Range("DragDownCell1")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DragDownCell1.AutoFill Destination:=wsDest.Range(DragDownCell1, wsDest.Cells(Lastrow, "B")), Type:=xFillDefault
```

Since `DragDownCell1` is already a range attributed to the `wsDest` worksheet, you don't need to specify `wsDest.Range(DragDownCell1)` - and on top of that you originally had

```
ws.Dest.Range("DragDownCell1")
```

Where `ws.Dest` is not the same as `wsDest` and `Range("DragDownCell1")` would be a `Named Range` i.e. a range named on the worksheet - you're actually just using a `Range` variable.

Comment: I get a compile error, method or data member not found for DragDownCell1

Comment: @jamheadart: You need to specify the Sheet also before `Cells(LastRow, "B")`

Comment: @FunThomas You're right, missed that, I've edited the answer and tested fine on any sheet in my book now.

Comment: Im so confused, sorry. I've changed `ws.Dest` to `wsDest`, if i remove both `wsDest` from the range to autofill and the destination i get a global error, if i only remove it from the range to be autofilled and have `DragDownCell1.AutoFill` I get a Range of object worksheet error. And if i remove both `wsDest`, i get a compile error, method or data member not found for `DragDownCell1`

Comment: Oh okay its working now, once i specified the sheet before `Cells(LastRow, "B")` @FunThomas Thanks everyone :)